# node-fetch returns 403 while curl returns 200

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, curl, node-fetch

I am trying to get a webpage to parse via node-fetch. node-fetch code looks like (AKA, copied from chrome inspector):

```
await fetch('https://www.scottycameron.com/store/user/login/', {
    headers: {
        'authority': 'www.scottycameron.com',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'sec-gpc': '1',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
    }
}).then(res => res.text())
```

Note that I changed the user agent in case they cared.
This returns a 403 not authorized from the web server.

However, when I copy the request from the inspector as a curl instead, and run it:

```
curl 'https://www.scottycameron.com/store/user/login/'   
-H 'authority: www.scottycameron.com'   
-H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1'   
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'   
-H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'   
-H 'sec-gpc: 1'   
-H 'sec-fetch-site: none'   
-H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate'   
-H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1'   
-H 'sec-fetch-dest: document'   
-H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9'   
--compressed
```

I get a 200 and the expected HTML document returned.

I don't understand how the web server can tell a difference between my node-fetch and my curl requests, given that they are coming from the same IP address I know that it isn't an IP whitelisting issue. I have also tried to add the http/v2 headers present on the call as headers (i.e. copy ':authority' header from inspector and add it as 'authority' header) to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo in the question, the `fetch` request goes to `https://www.scottycameron.com` but the curl goes to `https://www.scottycameron.com/store/user/login/`

Comment: Thanks @Amin, I will change those to be the same. Grabbed from different parts of debugging.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why node-fetch was getting a 403 but curl a 200?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using node-libcurl with cookiejar and modifying the user-agent header and that got around this. I'm not sure why fetch didn't seem to be doing what I needed to the user-agent header. Specifically the website I was trying to scrape was sniffing around and blocking my traffic based on some auxilliary information, and node-libcurl made it easier to -v this to see what package they were using and then research how to get around it.